# Tomcat 8 file download speed issue

Tags: java, performance, file, tomcat, download

I am using Tomcat 8 and I have functionality to download large files from tomcat server places in context docbase folder.
Below is the piece of code I am using the file to download:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();   
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment; filename=filename);  
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("filepath");  
int i;   
while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
    out.write(i);   
}   
fileInputStream.close();   
out.close();
```

When I download a file it is downloading with a speed of 65KB/sec
from the save server. If I place the same file in Apache server and try to download the download speed is 135KB/sec.

Could someone help me speed up the file download from Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that reading and writing a byte at a time to unbuffered streams is very inefficient. Looking at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22706158/1270789) and adapting it to your code, we could use:

```
// Assume ServletResponse response
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment; filename=filename);  
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("filepath");  

// Choose a bigger value if you want
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int n;
while ((n = fileInputStream.read(buffer) != -1)
{
    servletOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
fileInputStream.close();
servletOutputStream.close();
```

The above should be very efficient and hopefully equal or surpass your reported Apache speeds.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I tried implementing the way you suggested but still I am not seeing any increase in the download speed.